# Update PointAnnotation location android java

Tags: java, android, mapbox, dji-sdk, mapbox-android

I'm trying to show the location of a DJI Drone on the Mapbox map and constantly update it's location.
This is what I'm doing.

```
private void addDroneMarker(double latitude, double longitude){
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.aircraft_icon)).getBitmap();
        
        AnnotationPlugin annotationAPI = AnnotationPluginImplKt.getAnnotations(mapView);
        pointAnnotationManager = PointAnnotationManagerKt.createPointAnnotationManager(annotationAPI, new AnnotationConfig());
        
        PointAnnotationOptions pointAnnotationOptions = new PointAnnotationOptions()
                .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(longitude, latitude))
                .withIconImage(bitmap);
        dronePoint = pointAnnotationManager.create(pointAnnotationOptions);
    }

private void updateDroneMarker(double latitude, double longitude){
        dronePoint.setPoint(Point.fromLngLat(longitude, latitude));
        pointAnnotationManager.update(dronePoint);
    }

private void initFlightController(){
        BaseProduct product = FPVApplication.getProductInstance();
        if (product != null && product.isConnected()) {
            if (product instanceof Aircraft) {
                mFlightController = ((Aircraft) product).getFlightController();
            }
        }

        if (mFlightController != null) {
            mFlightController.setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onUpdate(FlightControllerState djiFlightControllerCurrentState) {
                    droneLocationLat = djiFlightControllerCurrentState.getAircraftLocation().getLatitude();
                    droneLocationLng = djiFlightControllerCurrentState.getAircraftLocation().getLongitude();

                    updateDroneMarker(droneLocationLat, droneLocationLng);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I create the drone annotation when the map loads and everytime the drone gives me a new location from the callback I update its location.
But my problem is, sometimes when I'm moving the map it gives me an error

`Error while setting camera options : std::exception`

This error could cause the application to crash with a Fatal Error

`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x787c881d0c in tid 17420 (RenderThread), pid 17347`

And I realized that this error was caused by the UpdateDroneMarker (maybe because of the camera Animation), so I'm trying to find a different way to update the drones location. Hope someone could help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running on ui thread. I don't know for specific for mapbox, however callbacks from dji are not running on ui thread, so I would try that first. Otherwise you will get all kinds of strange errors.